# Query timeout when Presto worker goes down

Tags: cassandra, presto

I have an infra of 8 nodes wherein I have one coordinator and 7 workers. My backend system is on Cassandra. I run queries on Cassandra through Presto.

I have plenty of reports run in the morning. But what I mainly see every day, Many of my reports get failed because of time out on any of the nodes.

When I went into logs and check, Sometimes my workers go out of network and when the coordinator doesn't connect with them. The whole query gets failed.

Is there any way to recover the same query when the worker is not available sometime. Either it can wait or can transfer that particular task to some other worker? Is there any way to recover from this situation?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Presto follows "fail fast" ideology. It is designed to ensure speed trading off checkpointing. As if now, there is no way to transfer jobs among workers and transitively no way to "resume" queries.

Alternatives:

- If you have control over worker nodes going away, you can implement graceful shutdown and take node away once all running tasks are complete and in the mean time stop scheduling more tasks.
- You can implement retries on top on the basis of exception types.

Relevant Pointers:

- https://www.qubole.com/blog/spot-nodes-in-presto-on-qubole/
- List item Graceful shutdown: [Presto Worker Graceful Shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786212/presto-worker-graceful-shutdown)